# How to use non-CA SSL certificate as root certificate in node.js?

Tags: node.js, ssl, openssl

So I want to have a non-CA certificate as root certificate in an TLS connection in node.js. However the certificate always seems to be considered a CA.

I am generating the root certificate with

```
openssl req -new -nodes -subj "/CN=ClientName1" -keyout client-key.pem -out client-csr.pem
openssl x509 -req -signkey client-key.pem -in client-csr.pem -out client-cert.pem -extfile v3.ext
```

(analogous for the server)

and a test-certificate like this

```
openssl req -new -nodes -subj "/CN=ClientName2" -keyout client-key2.pem -out client-csr2.pem
openssl x509 -req -in client-csr2.pem -out client-cert2.pem -extfile v3.ext -CA client-cert.pem -CAkey client-key.pem -CAcreateserial
```

with v3.ext being

```
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
```

Now the server accepts client-cert as well as client-cert2, however if I generate a third (client-cert3) signed by client-cert2, the server does not accept it. So the root certificate appears to be considered a CA no matter what. Is there a way around it without purposely generating a throwaway dummy root certificate which is only used to sign that one single client-cert?

I am using it like this:

```
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('server-key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('server-cert.pem'),

    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: true,

    ca: [fs.readFileSync('client-cert.pem')], 

    port: 15151 
};

var server = tls.createServer(options, function (socket) {});
```

P.S. Also when testing to use client-cert2.pem as root, the server does not accept clients using client-cert2, nor client-cert3, nor client-cert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything which is used to sign another certificate must have the appropriate key usage restrictions. If the the usage restrictions do not allow a certificate to work as a CA you cannot work around it because validation of the certificate chain is done by the client and not by the server.

Comment: I was thinking the basicConstraints=CA:FALSE would do just that. How else can I restrict the usage to not allow signing by the generated certificate?

Comment: @Marius: The certificates are validated by the client. It does not matter what the server accepts because it only sends the certificates to the client.

Comment: Yes I know, but the client accepts the self-signed root certificate if and only if it has keyCertSign flag set. Maybe my example is not the best because I use two-way authentication (both server and client present a certificate to the other side) and in my example it's the server rejecting the client certificate or accepting it as a CA with keyCertSign privilege. But the problem is the same other way round: The root either has to have keyCertSign, giving it more privileges than I want it to, or it doesnt and gets rejected itself.

Comment: @Marius: exactly, the client rejects the certificate if it can not validate it. And it does it on purpose because what you want is to use a certificate to sign another certificate, without the signer having the appropriate permissions - i.e. non-standard and insecure behavior. If what you want would be possible anybody having a certificate could just create new certificates. To say it again: what you want is not possible, at least not without changing the client by introducing a serious security vulnerability into it.

Comment: Actually I don't want to use a certificate to sign another certificate - rather the contrary, I want to create a root certificate that cannot sign another certificate. But whatever I try I cannot get the client to accept the root certificate unless I create the root certificate with signing privileges flag on it (keyCertSign).

Comment: @Marius: A root certificate is something which is on the top of the certificate hierarchy. This means at must have the ability to sign other certificates, because hierarchy and trust chain are solely established through signing. Thus what you want is in effect something which cannot sign other certificates (requirement CA:false) but which is able to sign other certificates (requirement: root certificate). This is obviously not possible.

Comment: "but which is able to sign other certificates (requirement: root certificate)" Why is that a requirement for a root certificate? Does a root certificate specify itself as issuer and therefore if it doesn't have keyCertSign this is a violation? (making it an invalid certificate)?

Comment: @Marius: I'm not sure that you understand the concept of certificate hierarchies and what a root certificate really is. Maybe [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778623(v=ws.10).aspx) helps to explain the concepts. Once you understand it it should be obvious to you that a root CA must have the ability to sign other certificates.

Comment: Thank you, but the article doesn't give a clear answer either what it means for a root certificate to be self-signed. I am aware that usually the whole system is used for certificate hierarchies with a chain-of-trust, but in my usecase I just want to use the technology for direct, secure end-to-end communication where neither party can mess with the certificate details (by using it to sign a new certificate with other CN in it). I know this could be done by creating a root-ca and having the root-ca sign a cert without signing-rights, but as mentioned in the OP I want to know if thats necessary

Comment: @Marius: Since it looks like you don't want to use the mechanism of trust chains to validate your certificates this leaves only direct trusts to the certificate, i.e. certificate or public key pinning. There are no trust chains without the chain part, i.e. the signing. And for signing you need the appropriate properties of the certificates, no way aorund.

Comment: Since node.js' tlsSocket does not seem to have a built-in feature for pinning I guess using a single-use root certificate and throwing away its key is the simpler and more versatile option. Thank you for your help. :)